# Can I use 2 languages to make 1 program?

Tags: c, windows, perl, programming-languages, 64-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing a program in 2 languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886086/writing-a-program-in-2-languages)

*Note: I've seen [Writing a program in 2 languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886086/writing-a-program-in-2-languages) but found no good answer IMO.*

Can I use 2, 3, or even 4 languages to make a single program? What do I need to do to accomplish this (probably in Perl and C)? I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Really need more information on what you're trying to do.... Some scenario's are possible, as a matter of fact, I just finished a GWT website that communicates with a .net server (C#) backend for data access.

Comment: What did you not like about the answers you found? They seemed pretty good to me. Perhaps you would get better answers if you asked a more precise question.

Comment: This question adds nothing beyond the question cited.

Comment: If you want Perl's regexps in C, there are C(++) regexp libraries available. If you want Perl's hash tables and other useful data structures, that exists too.

Comment: @Don Roby, This is not even close to an exact duplicate of the linked node.

Comment: @ikegami, It asks exactly the same question, and the answer to both is simply "Yes, and we've been doing it since day one.".

Comment: @Don Roby, The linked post does not ask how to link Perl and C together. Not even close. Not the same question.

Comment: "probably C and Perl" does not sound very specific to me.

Answer (score 4):

As people have already mentioned, yes you can as long as there are bindings. [`Inline::C`](http://p3rl.org/Inline%3a%3aC) provides easy access to C from Perl, although I find XS to be almost as easy once you start to get the hang of it.

For now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Inline C => <<'END_C';
char* name () {
  return "Joel";
}
END_C

print name() . "\n";
```

So that begs the question, what are you trying to do? If you need something more in-depth, you can look at the source for my (work in progress) [`Math::GSLx::ODEIV2`](https://github.com/jberger/Math-GSLx-ODEIV2).

Answer (score 3):

The relevant Perl documentation is [perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) if you want to execute Perl code from C and [perlxstut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxstut.html) if you want to execute C code from Perl.

Comment: and [perlcall](http://p3rl.org/call) if you want to call Perl code from inside C inside Perl

Comment: and look for embedding documentation for other languages like lua, python, etc

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use some of the Perl modules in the
[Inline::*](https://metacpan.org/search?q=Inline%3A%3A) namespace.  For example, [Inline::C](https://metacpan.org/module/Inline%3a%3aC) allows you to write C subroutines directly in your Perl source file.  The module transparently handles compiling the C routines to a shared library and dynamically loading the library.  There are 'Inline' modules for a variety of languages - in varying states of completeness and support.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use as many languages as you want. You just need the proper tools to **bind** the units together. Each language has its own builtin support to interoperate with other languages, and often libraries that do that as well. The exact tools you need would depend on the languages you use, but every language I know supports *at least* binding to C functions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out chapter *21.3. Extending Perl (Using C from Perl)* in [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004927).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Perl binding for C, take a look at [swig](http://www.swig.org/).